# USB (wireless) keyboard not recognised during install

Tags: system-installation, usb, keyboard

I'm just trying my first trip into the world of Ubuntu.

Trying to install from CD on to a virgin machine, I get the initial language prompt, select 'English', I get the Ubuntu install options, select 'Install Ubuntu Server'.  I'm then presented with a further 'Language for installation' screen.  At this point my keyboard stops working!

Some specifics:

- I'm using a Logitech wireless USB keyboard - it works fine on another machine;
- Machine is a ProLiant Micorserver N54L (No PS/2 ports);
- BIOS USB support is set to Legacy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with fixes released. I suggest a good read:

[alternate iso missing hid-logitech-dj driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/975198)

Otherwise use a wired USB keyboard for the install, but you may have problems during GRUB selection if fixes aren't applied.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :-)  Unfortunately I've no idea how to incorporate a patch in the build to be placed on the installation CD, I just downloaded 12.04 LTS, so think I'll have to buy a wired keyboard and hope that works.

Comment: Broken in 14.04.3 LTS.